# Kubeconfig context returns "You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized) error

Tags: kubernetes

I am running kube on a cluster of nodes. When i set the context on the cluster I get an error that says "error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)" when i try to run kubectl get pods

If I unset the current-context the error goes away and i can view my pods and nodes. So my guess is it has something to do with my kubeconfig but I'm not sure where i got it wrong.

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /home/user/ssl/ca.pem
    server: https://<ip for my master node>
  name: default-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: default-cluster
    user: user
  name: kubeflow
current-context: kubeflow
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: user
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/user/ssl/client-ca.pem
    client-key: /home/user/ssl/client-ca-key.pem
```

EDIT:

Kube version 1.14

```
user@kube01:~$ kubectl  version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1", GitCommit:"b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-08T17:11:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1", GitCommit:"b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-08T17:02:58Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

- Running on a cluster with 3 master nodes and 4 workers.
  Not on GCP or any cloud platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I unset the current-context the error goes away and i can view my pods and nodes. So my guess is it has something to do with my kubeconfig but I'm not sure where i got it wrong.

That very likely means you are running `kubectl` on the master nodes themselves, and the master nodes are listening on `:8080` with the unauthenticated port (since `kubectl` uses `http://127.0.0.1:8080` by default if there is no kubeconfig)

So yes, it's very likely due to your cert being signed by a CA that the apiserver does not trust.

You can check that via:

```
openssl x509 -in /home/user/ssl/client-ca.pem -noout -text
```

and then look at the CA and compare the `issuer` from your `client-ca` against the `subject` of your CA:

```
openssl x509 -in /home/user/ssl/ca.pem -noout -text
```

I am sure there are some fingerprints and serial numbers and that kind of stuff that need to match up, but I don't have that `openssl` command line handy

Comment: yup there was some problems with the cert setup, got my administrator to regenerate the certs and after pointing them to the correct certs, it worked. Thanks

Comment: Just in case anyone stumbles on this page with my problem, make sure you remember to ```kubectl config set-credentials``` after generating all the certificates